# Connect Cloud SQL MySQL From Local MySQL Workbench - Connection Success but cannot connect database server

Tags: database-connection, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I am using Cloud SQL for the last 2 months. I whitelisted my Office IP in Connection. I was using it fine for the last 2 months.
Yesterday I add another Node Pool in the GKE cluster. (I don't think it's relevant with cloud SQL but still informing) After that, I can't able to connect it from my office PC by MySQL Workbench. Test Connection is a success but after it shows a different message.
[image]

Our Application is fine because we were using Cloud SQL proxy.
I remove and add again Office IP in the Cloud SQL connection. But the same problem remains.

Comment: I am using pgAdmin 4 for Google Cloud SQL Postgres. My IP is whitelisted there. I can reach my google cloud SQL Postgres database. So I don't think my IP has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

After restarting the Google Cloud SQL MySQL instance then my problem was solved.